# Python web scrape not pulling data

Tags: python-3.x

Missing something here.  Is the first code below I get exactly what I needed to be printed out.  However in the second code I can seem to get the same information I need to print out.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.lowes.ca/refrigerators/whirlpool-wrf560sfym-197-cu-ft-3-french-door-refrigerator-stainless-steel_g1340277.html"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

g_data = soup.find_all("div", id="prodNameMob")
p_data = soup.find_all("div", id="1price999")

for g, p in zip(g_data, p_data):
    print (g.text, p.text)
```

Here is the second code.  In this code I use the Main URL and then add the links to get a specific page and then grab certain information within that specific page.  However, unlike the first piece of code I can not get the prodNameMob and the 1price999 to print out.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

b = open('csv/lowesfridges.csv', 'w', newline='')
a = csv.writer(b,delimiter=',')

url = "https://www.lowes.ca/appliances/refrigerators/?pg=1"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

myfulllinks = []
mainurl = "http://www.leons.ca"
links = soup.find_all("div", class_="l searchImg fltns center")

for link in links:
    myfulllinks ='{}{}'.format(mainurl, link.find('a').get('href'))
    print(myfulllinks)

    full_url = myfulllinks
    r1 = requests.get(full_url)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.content, "lxml")

    g_data = soup.find_all("div", id="prodNameMob")
    p_data = soup.find_all("div", id="1price999")

    for g, p, l in zip(g_data, p_data, myfulllinks):
        c = (g.get_text(strip=True).replace("\n", " "),    p.get_text(strip=True).replace("\n", " "), myfulllinks)
        print(g.get_text(strip=True).replace("\n", " "), p.get_text(strip=True).replace("\n", " "), myfulllinks)
    a.writerow(c)
b.close()
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some error in this source, after fixing code working well.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

b = open('lowesfridges.csv', 'w', newline='')
a = csv.writer(b,delimiter=',')

url = "https://www.lowes.ca/appliances/refrigerators/?pg=1"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

myfulllinks = []
mainurl = "http://www.lowes.ca" # Wrond domain
links = soup.find_all("div", class_="l searchImg fltns center")

for link in links:
    myfulllinks ='{}{}'.format(mainurl, link.find('a').get('href'))
    print(myfulllinks)

    full_url = myfulllinks
    r1 = requests.get(full_url)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.content, "lxml")

    g_data = soup1.find_all("div", id="prodNameMob") # soup1 should be used
    p_data = soup1.find_all("div", id="1price999") # soup1 should be used

    for g, p, l in zip(g_data, p_data, myfulllinks):
        c = (g.get_text(strip=True).replace("\n", " "),    p.get_text(strip=True).replace("\n", " "), myfulllinks)
        print(g.get_text(strip=True).replace("\n", " "), p.get_text(strip=True).replace("\n", " "), myfulllinks)
    a.writerow(c)
    b.flush() # save to disk immediately
b.close()
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't even notice that I didn't change them to soup1.  Thanks